# Installed Office 365 Home Premium, got Office Professional Plus 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, uninstall

There was MS Office professional plus 2013 installed on Windows 7. I uninstalled it. Then I bought MS Office 365 Home Premium and installed it.
But when I run it, product activation window appears that says that I have MS Office Professional Plus! And it must be activated in 3 weeks.
I tried 3 times to remove office, did manual removal as described here: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501/
But it don't work. I'm still getting professional plus :-(

Answer (score 0):

From admin command prompt I ran:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15"
cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus
```

It showed me some old professional plus key. I removed it with:

```
cscript ospp.vbs /unpkey:value
```

And it works!